How many unique combinations of 4 digit numbers are there? Repetitions are allowed but order does not matter. 0's are allowed.
My guess is 715. There are 5 types of combinations: abcd, aabc, aabb, aaab, & aaaa. I think these values are (10 choose 4)+10*(9 choose 2)+(10 choose 2)+10*9+10 = 715.
Does this make sense or am I missing something?

Computing abcd as $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{4}~$ is apparently allowing the leftmost digit to equal $~0.$  If this is not allowed, the adjustment is $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{4} - \binom{9}{3}.$

My guess of 715 is equivalent to (13 choose 4). Using bars and stars, I think this would be equivalent to my answer. Make sense?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.
